# Porque uma variável sem valor é considerada não iniciada?

Tags: php, variáveis

Percebi que o PHP retorna que uma variável não foi iniciada se não tiver nenhum valor atribuído á ela. Na minha opinião, não faz sentido porque a variável já foi iniciada e aguarda um valor.

Exemplo:

```
class Users {
    public $username;

    public function __construct() {
        if(isset($this->username))
            echo 'variável foi iniciada';
        else
            echo 'variável não foi iniciada';
    }
}
```

Qual o motivo de acontecer isso?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se parâmetros são passados, então `isset` retornará `TRUE`, somente se todos os parâmetros são definidos.

Uma variável não iniciada é equivalente à constante PHP `NULL`. Logo a função `isset` retornará `FALSE`.

Se você está lidando com as propriedades do objeto e quer "avaliar" o valor de `NULL`, você pode usar: `property_exists` em vez de `isset`:

```
<?php

class minhaClass{
    public $mine;
    private $xpto;
    static protected $teste;

    function teste() {
        var_dump(property_exists($this, 'xpto')); //true
    }
}

var_dump(property_exists('minhaClass', 'mine'));   //true
var_dump(property_exists(new minhaClass, 'mine')); //true
var_dump(property_exists('minhaClass', 'xpto'));   //true, para PHP 5.3.0
var_dump(property_exists('minhaClass', 'bar'));    //false
var_dump(property_exists('minhaClass', 'test'));   //true, para PHP 5.3.0
minhaClass::teste();

?>
```

Para complementar, veja essa tabela abaixo:
F = false
T = true

```
        isset  is_null ===null  ==null  empty
 null |   F   |   T   |   T   |   T   |   T   |
unset |   F   |   T   |   T   |   T   |   T   |
  ""  |   T   |   F   |   F   |   T   |   T   |
  []  |   T   |   F   |   F   |   T   |   T   |
    0 |   T   |   F   |   F   |   T   |   T   |
false |   T   |   F   |   F   |   T   |   T   |
 true |   T   |   F   |   F   |   F   |   F   |
    1 |   T   |   F   |   F   |   F   |   F   |
   \0 |   T   |   F   |   F   |   F   |   F   |
```

Answer (score 8):

Existe uma diferença entre declarar uma variável e atribuir um valor a ela.

Declarar significa que você indicou que uma variável existirá em determinado contexto. Mas só isto. Em PHP se a variável não tiver um valor atribuído, ela é nula.

Só quando você atribui um valor é que a variável passa ser utilizável.

No seu exemplo a variável só foi declarada e não inicializada.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que seja apenas um problema de nomenclatura e entendimento do método `isset`.

Da [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.
>
> If a variable has been unset with unset(), it will no longer be set.
>   isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to
>   NULL. Also note that a null character ("\0") is not equivalent to the
>   PHP NULL constant.

Você mencionou a palavra "iniciada". Em entendimento comum da palavra, uma variável iniciada é **uma variável que teve algum valor atribuído**. No exemplo mostrado por você, isto não ocorreu efetivamente.

Mas é normal a confusão. No mundo Java, uma variável pode ser considerada iniciada atribuindo o valor `null` nela, diferente do método `isset` do PHP que não considera uma variável nula como iniciada.

Answer (score 1):

A variável é apenas uma **referência** a um `valor/objeto`.

Existe uma **diferença entre declarar uma variável e inicializar uma variável**. No seu exemplo você declarou a variável mas não inicializou ela. Ou seja, não atribuiu nenhum `valor/objeto` à ela. Assim, o valor dela ainda está `null`.

Answer (score 1):

No PHP, as variáveis são avaliadas como `false` por `isset` em dois casos:

- Quando ela não existe
- Quando ela é `null`.

Para os dois casos abaixo, a avaliação de `isset` retornará `false`.

```
var_dump(isset($a));

$b = null;


var_dump(isset($b));
```

**Detalhe adicional**:Não tem relação com a pergunta, mas é importante ressaltar que, em caso de verificação de índices de `arrays`, não é recomendado para alguns casos o uso de `isset`, mas sim de `array_keys_exists`.

Exemplo 1:

```
$a = array(1 => 'um', 2 => null);

var_dump(isset($a[1])); // bool(true);

var_dump(isset($a[2])); // bool(false);
```

Exemplo 2:

```
var_dump(array_keys_exists(1, $a)); // bool(true);

var_dump(array_keys_exists(2, $a)); // bool(true);
```

Como foi dito, para valores `null`, `isset` retornará `false` também.
Observe que, `array_keys_exists` verifica a existência do índice, ao invés de verifiar se o valor é `null`.